# switching from guest to host in virt-manager without mouse

Tags: virt-manager

In order to switch from a guest to the host, we must move the mouse along the top edge of guest screen.
A little toolbar is displayed at the top.
**BUT**
When the mouse freezes in the guest, how to proceed the switching ?